# An issue when I want to get Sunday of this week

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I write these code to get Sunday of this week.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [cal components: NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

// I want to get the sunday
[components setWeekday:1];
NSDate* d = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"Sunday:%@", d);
```

But I got the result: Feb 25, 2012, I think the correct result should be Feb 26, 2012.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: oops never mind I was looking at March.  :)

Comment: Maybe the `NSMonthCalendarUnit` is throwing it off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize more components:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    [components setWeek:i];
    [components setWeekday:1];
    d = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"Sunday,Week %d:%@", i,d);   
}

Output:

Sunday,Week 0:2011-12-25 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 1:2012-01-01 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 2:2012-01-08 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 3:2012-01-15 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 4:2012-01-22 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 5:2012-01-29 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 6:2012-02-05 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 7:2012-02-12 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 8:2012-02-19 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 9:2012-02-26 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 10:2012-03-04 08:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 11:2012-03-11 08:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Strange, using your code, my output is:

Sunday,Week 0:2011-12-24 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 1:2011-12-31 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 2:2012-01-07 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 3:2012-01-14 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 4:2012-01-21 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 5:2012-01-28 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 6:2012-02-04 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 7:2012-02-11 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 8:2012-02-18 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 9:2012-02-25 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 10:2012-03-03 16:00:00 +0000
Sunday,Week 11:2012-03-10 16:00:00 +0000

Comment: That is strange. Are you on the other side of the international date line?  :)